# Searching records by comparing another list of records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of records from database table, what query should i use to get records from another table by comparing each record from first table search result.

i am using foreach loop to compare each record form second table. Is there way to get it directly using Entity Framework?

```
            /// Get all Areas for each program in the survey
        /// 
        if (programs.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var program in programs)
            {
                var a = db.Areas.Where(r => r.ProgramId == program.Id);

                areas.AddRange(a);  // Storing areas in list
            }    
        }

        // Get all products for each area
        foreach (var a in areas)
        {
            var ids = db.Products.Where(r => r.AreaId == a.Id);
            prods.AddRange(ids);
        }
```

Comment: In order for anyone to be able to help you, you'll need to provide some details on the type of objects you're searching for, what objects you're using to compare. Please show some code that you've tried so far. As of now, we have no idea where to start.

Comment: so what you have tried

Comment: Try using the Contains method.  It's very powerful, but under-used when it comes to Entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Select areas using collection of your program entities

```
if (programs.Count() > 0)
{
   var progrmIds = programs.Select(e => e.Id).ToArray();  
   var areasResult = db.Areas.Where(r => programIds.Contains(r.ProgramId));
   areas.AddRange(areasResult);  // Storing areas in list
}
```

2) Select products base on the areas

```
var areaIds = areas.Select(e => e.Id).ToArray();
var allProductsByAreas = db.Products.Where(r =>reaIds.Contains(r.AreaId))
```

I am sure there is a better way to do it with joins, but this is the closest way to what you have right now and you will not generate a query for each area & program

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please:

```
var areaIds = areas.Select(a => a.Id).ToArray();
prods = db.Products.Where(r => areaIds.Contains(r.AreaId));
```

`Contains` method will work if you're using EF 4 or higher.